# How to change H1 color only for pages

Tags: css

This one should be easy for you guys. As the title says, I only want to change the color for pages and not posts.

I've tried this and some variations of it but no luck

```
.page h1 {color:#ED3709 !important;}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'm an idiot, sorted it out now

Comment: does the body element of a page have class 'page'?

Comment: Post your solution please, in case others have the same problem :D. (After 24 hours, please accept it too to take it off the 'unanswered' pile :D)

Comment: The code was right but I didn't change the color; I copy and pasted the original h1 code from my stylesheet... it's been a long day.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and answer it anyway. Assuming the theme is built right (I'll get to that in a second) `.page` and `.single` are applied to the `<body>` tag for pages and posts respectively.

In order to ensure those classes are applied, ensure the following template tag is used:
    `<body <?php body_class(); ?> >`

Then, the example you wrote should work correctly assuming your CSS cascades properly